# How to select a value from one table where two separate pairs of conditions are met in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm sorry in advance if this is a bad question. I'm new to SQL and haven't been able to find the answer myself.

I have two tables. The first table contains an id and unique words. The second table contains an id, property_name and property_value and can have multiple properties for each word.

**word**

```
+----+------+
| id | word |
+----+------+
|  1 | dog  |
|  2 | tree |
|  3 | dang |
|  4 | frog |
+----+------+
```

**property**

```
+----+---------------+----------------+
| id | property_name | property_value |
+----+---------------+----------------+
|  1 | letters       | 3              |
|  1 | first_letter  | d              |
|  2 | letters       | 4              |
|  2 | first_letter  | t              |
|  3 | letters       | 4              |
|  3 | first_letter  | d              |
|  4 | letters       | 4              |
|  4 | first_letter  | f              |
+----+---------------+----------------+
```

I want to select a word where two sets of conditions are met. Below is the pseudo-code of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
SELECT word
WHERE 
1) (property_name = 'letters' and property_value = '3')
2) (property_name = 'first_letter' and property_value = 'd')
```

First I searched google for examples of joining one table to another table where multiple properties can exist for each value in the first table. I had a lot of difficulty describing what I was searching for and wasn't able to find anything on google. I also searched stack overflow for similar questions, but the questions were only vaguely similar and the answers didn't work for me. All together, this is my third day in a row trying to find this solution.

Below are a few of my attempts:

I have tried nesting an and statement.

```
SELECT w.word
FROM word w
LEFT JOIN property p ON (w.id = p.id)
WHERE ((p.property_name = 'letters' and p.property_value = '3') and
(p.property_name = 'first_letter' and p.property_value = 'd'))
GROUP BY w.word
```

I also tried multiple left joins.

```
SELECT w.word
FROM word w
LEFT JOIN property p ON (w.id = p.id)
WHERE (p.property_name = 'letters' and p.property_value = '3')
LEFT JOIN property p ON (w.id = p.id)
WHERE (p.property_name = 'first_letter' and p.property_value = 'd')
GROUP BY w.word
```

The first attempt above returns a joined table where only the first condition is met. The second attempt returns a syntax error.

There were more failed attempts but I didn't include them for brevity.

For the pseudocode I wrote above, my desired result is:

```
dog
```

I just don't know how to write a query that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using INTERSECT you can write a query that is efficient, intuitive and in fact very similar to what you first wrote:

```
SELECT word FROM words
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM properties WHERE property_name = 'letters' AND property_value = '3'
  INTERSECT
  SELECT id FROM properties WHERE property_name = 'first_letter' AND property_value = 'd'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

first, don't use `left join` if you want to get matching `property` to your `word`
second, no need to use `group by`, you are not using any `aggregation function`.

```
select w.word
from word w
inner join property p on w.id = p.id and p.property_name = 'letters' and p.property_value = '3'
inner join property p2 on w.id = p2.id  and p2.property_name = 'first_letter' and p2.property_value = 'd'
```

or you can use `exists` keyword

```
select w.word
from word w
where 
    exists (select 1 from property p where w.id = p.id 
        and p.property_name = 'letters' and p.property_value = '3')
    and
    exists (select 1 from property p where w.id = p.id 
        and p.property_name = 'first_letter' and p.property_value = 'd')
```